# React component renders many times

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple react structure which loads more items as it scrolls down with this structure :

```
function handleScroll() {
    if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight || isFetching) return;

        setIsFetching(true);
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFetching) return;
    fetchMoreListItems();
}, [isFetching]);



const fetchMoreListItems = () => {
    getData(state.page, Config.ADS_PER_ROW, dispatch, state.sortBy, false)
    setTimeout(() => {
        setIsFetching(false);
    }, 1000);
}
```

which then maps through my data as such :

```
state.data.map((r, i) => {
         return (
           <tbody key={r.id}>
     {!state.loading && i && i % 20 === 0 ? <AddRender /> : null}
```

However the `<AddRender />` runs at least 5 times every time I scroll down and has cause quite a number of issues for me.

how can I avoid this component to be run multiple times without command ?

Comment: You can add some throttling for your scroll event with lodash or copy-paste some gist and get rid of the trouble. Let me know if you need a full answer on how to implement this

Comment: Please enlighten me

Comment: codesandbox link would be helpful :)